# Get a multiple value listing of related node IDs using Relation module and Views node ID field

Tags: 7, views, entities

**The situation**

The awesome Relation module uses so called *endpoints* in a dummy field to show related entities to a given entity.

Sadly there is (still) no way to (really) decide what field values of the *related Entities* exactly *these endpoints* are which we want to show. You are only able to decide between "endpoints" or "endpoints and fields", which both result mostly in the same: a list of the linked titles of the related entities, more or less cluttering, depending on your additional relation fields.

**The question**

Is there something I miss to achieve this? I would like to prevent using performance hogs Views field view for such small task like a list of related node IDs per row in a Views table of listed nodes. Is there any work around or advice somebody can give? Thanks in advance.

**Maybe related issues I found on DSX here:**

- [Views related nodes with contextual filters multiple-value handling problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138434/views-related-nodes-with-contextual-filters-multiple-value-handling-problem)
- [create relation between two nodes using the relation module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32030/create-relation-between-two-nodes-using-the-relation-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around which could come in mind to an experienced Drupal site builder is to use Views module to get more flexibility in showing other fields of related entities listed instead of titles, by using the Views relationship advanced settings in connection with an existing field of related items like node ID.

Sadly the multiple value field handler of Views only appears on the Relation endpoint field itself, added directly in your Views view, but not in the node ID field by using the proper Views relationship to the relation <-> for this purpose.

The expected behavior is, that you are able to activate and modify multiple values of the related node ID field now in the node ID field settings like you did in the endpoints field before. But sadly that's not the case. You will always get the first related node ID or many duplicate records depending on how much related items you have with each related node ID per Views view row.